# Can't Create Intent in Preference Listener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-preferences

I have created a `Preference` to allow the user to log out. This is what I have in my `root_preferences.xml`:

```
<Preference
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
    android:key="logout_preference"
    app:allowDividerAbove="true"
    app:allowDividerBelow="true"
    app:singleLineTitle="true"
    app:title="Log Out" />
```

In my `SettingsActivity` I have this code:

```
val logOutPreference: Preference = findPreference("logout_preference")!!
logOutPreference.onPreferenceClickListener =
    Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
        true
    }
```

The problem is it won't allow me to create an `Intent` in my `OnPreferenceClickListener` and when I remove the `Intent` code and just leave `auth.signOut()` my app crashes. How do I fix this? I want it so that when the user goes to the `Settings` screen, they can click on the `log_preference` and it will log them out of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your lamba `this` refers to the click listener.
Change it like this

```
val intent = Intent(this@ActivityNameHere, MainActivity::class.java)
```

where `ActivityNamerHere` is the name of your activity.

Edit: If you're in a fragment, then to this

```
val intent = Intent(requireContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
```

Comment: I did `this@SettingsFragment` because my code is inside `class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat()` and I'm still getting an error. I also tried `SettingsActivity` since the `SettingsFragment` class is inside `SettingsActivity` class and I'm getting `Unresolved reference: @SettingsActivity` error.

Comment: You need to pass a ``Context`` in for that first parameter - a ``Fragment`` isn't a context. Try ``this@SettingsFragment.context`` (which can be null, but shouldn't be if someone's clicking on a thing)